# How do I query multiple tables for the most recent entry in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables: posts, comments and replies

```
Posts
id
user_id (fk)
content
created_at
updated_at

Comments
id
user_id (fk)
post_id (fk)
content
created_at
updated_at

Replies
id
user_id (fk)
post_id (fk)
comment_id (fk)
content
created_at
updated_at
```

Right now I have posts ordered by created_at in desc order to get the latest created one at the very top when displayed. What I need it to do is place the post that was most recently created OR the post with the most recent comment/reply at the very top instead. So far I have tried...

```
SELECT posts.*, comments.*, replies.*
FROM posts
LEFT JOIN comments
ON posts.id = comments.post_id
LEFT JOIN replies
ON comments.id = replies.comment_id
```

But that only gets me all the individual posts, its comments and replies in one row. What should I do next?

Comment: What columns do you want returned? Because the current query you have will return multiple columns named `user_id`, `id`, `created_at` etc.

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: oh sorry about, i'm trying to sort them by created_at and want to display the contents for all posts, comments and replies as well as their respective creators (users) and post and/or comment they belong to (in regards to replies)